# How to use postgreSQL to store user credentials in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

Is it possible in GeoServer that instead of using .xml to save all user’s credentials can I use PostgreSQL, and then use those credentials to login?

PS: I tried JDBC driver, but not working. I can see new users getting created in the database, but I'm not able to use those credentials to log in

[image]

#geoserver

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure you are using the [`JDBC AUthentication`](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/providers.html#jdbc-authentication) provider correctly. These [training notes from GeoSolutions](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/educational/en/security/jdbc_authentication.html) walk you through the set up.

JDBC Authentical provider
[image]

Roles created
[image]

Comment: Yeah, so when I create connection, I’m able to use PostgreSQL credentials to log in, but when I create new user in geoserver, then I can’t login using his credentials

Comment: please update your question using the [edit] link to add details of how you have set your authentication providers (it sounds like there is one before the JDBC one)

Comment: Hi Ian, I have added some screenshots, Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @IanTurton are we required to manually add the users to geoserver, or are they materialized when establishing the jdbc authentication provider (in our case postgresql with existing users)?